# jquery show images with same height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am having an problem placing images in a neat manner in my site.

So what I have is: Using ajax I get a bunch of image URLS as JSON.

in Jquery I am looping these and printing them into a div like this:

```
$('.product').click(function(){
        $.post( 
            "ajax.php",
            { 
                prodId: productId,
                action: "getProductImages" 
            },
            function(data) 
            {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                newDiv = "";
                jQuery.each(obj, function(key,value) 
                {
                    newDiv += '<img src="'+value+'">';
                });
                $("#prod-images").empty();
                $(newDiv).appendTo('#prod-images');
            }
        );
    });
```

This works fine and shows the product images in a div as I want it to show. The problem is that some images have different height and width and they look awkward and ugly the way they are rendered now. How can I show them in a neat set with same height and width, or atleast same height?

I tried putting it in div tag and span tag, but it totally messes up what I already have. I am not very good with frontend technology so any help is appreciated! Even a library will help me...

Thanks in advance

Comment: give each image a class and in that class fix the height to a desired value

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `$.post` instead of `$.get` (or `$.ajax`, which does a GET in the background)?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `height` and `width` attributes in the `img` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try css with `img` tag

```
img
{

    height: 150px; //your height
}
```

This will set the height of the image and scale the image width keeping the ratio.

If you want to apply to some specific image then define that in css to . like for all image in div which class is  `img-div`

```
.img-div img
{
}
```

Comment: I want the height and width to be similar because I realized that when I have images with different width, the layout goes for a toss. I think what I need is a square inside which the image should get placed without losing aspect ratio...

Comment: then just define the width too with height

Comment: that will lose aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a CSS class in your img tag.

```
.media-small {
    width: auto
    height: 300px; /* or em */
}
```

To answer your question you could also get tricky with a *frame* div to maintain the ratio if you don't mind the clipping

```
div.media-frame {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

img.media {
    overflow: hidden
    width: 300px
    height: auto /* you may need to play with your defaults */
}
```

Comment: That looks better. Is there a way I can specify a width, (such that the image does not get skewed)

Comment: Any idea how thats done? are you talking about iframe?